# Return and destructuring in one line

Tags: javascript, destructuring

My question may be stupid but I would like to be able to reduce the map function in one single line.

```
const data = [
  { a: 2, b: 8, c:9 },
  { a: 4, b: 0, c:5 },
];

data.map(obj => { 
  const {a, b} = obj 
  return {a, b};
});
```

I instinctively try this solution.

```
data.map(obj => { return {a, b} = obj });
```

Can you tell me why this solution does not work on Chrome ?
Thanks you,
Jonathan Giamporcaro

Comment: TLDR: No, but you can destructure the argument and then use an object literal.

Comment: Do you try `data.map(({a, b})=>({a, b}))`

Comment: Thanks @imcvampire 